# PhaserJs/javascript: My array is updating too many times

Tags: javascript, arrays, phaser-framework

So I have some code making a simple inventory, like this:

```js
else if (this.inventory.indexOf(tileType) != -1) {
              this.inventory[this.inventory.indexOf(tileType) + 1] =
                this.inventory[this.inventory.indexOf(tileType) + 1] - 1;
              console.log(this.inventory);
              return;
```

In phasers update function, i'm using `this.input.manager.activePointer.isDown` as my event trigger, and it subtracts it for as long as the mouse is down, which results in at least 6 updates cycles for the quickest clicks

I've tried methods like return; etc. , but it always goes subtracting multiple times.
So is there any javascript method i could use, or a better phaser input event?

Comment: Can you not just use a normal [`mousedown event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousedown_event)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Geshode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75317581/1679286) mentioned in the comments, I would also setup the mouse event in the `create` function, and remove the other mouse code from the `update` function. ([checkout the documentation for details](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Input.InputPlugin.html))

Since this event will be executed only once per click/touch.

```
function create(){
    ...
    this.input.on('pointerdown', () => {
        if (this.inventory.indexOf(tileType) != -1) {
            this.inventory[this.inventory.indexOf(tileType) + 1] = 
                this.inventory[this.inventory.indexOf(tileType) + 1] - 1;
            console.log(this.inventory);
            ...
         }
    });
}
```

> Check out these official Mouse [examples](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/category/input/mouse)

**Update example:**

The idea is to make all local variables needed in the event function, that are created / used in the `update` function with *"scene properties"*.

Out of `tileType` you would have to make `this.tileType`, and so on. *(you just have to beware of naming collisions)*

**How it could look like:**

```
function create(){
    ...
    this.input.on('pointerdown', () => {
        // the tileType is now a property of the current scene
        if (this.inventory.indexOf(this.tileType) != -1) {
            this.inventory[this.inventory.indexOf(this.tileType) + 1] = 
                this.inventory[this.inventory.indexOf(this.tileType) + 1] - 1;
            console.log(this.inventory);
            ...
         }
    });
}
```

> Or better use a "gameState" object. In the `create` function add `this.gameState = {};` and than each variable you would like to add / access, just write `this.gameState.tileType = 1;`. So long the context (`this`) is the scene, this should work, and there will be no naming problem.

Comment: This Actually doesnt work, as it needs variables constantly updated in the update section, like the tile type, etc, so is there anyway to have it work with variables in the update section?

Comment: @VatsaPandey **this is the way how one would do it**, trust me. **If** you need access to variables in the event function from the `update` function, just make them properties on the current scene. _(and if there are too many make a gameState object)_ I updated my answer.

Comment: I tried it, and it worked partially, and i posted the weird issue in this question because it was too big for a comment

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75349545/my-phaser-3-gamestate-object-is-working-in-some-places-and-not-in-others

Comment: @VatsaPandey if possible consider accepting my answer since it solved your initial question.