# My Phaser 3 GameState Object is working in some places and not in others

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

So I have A phaser three game state object I've been implementing, which looks like this:

```js
this.gameState = {
      inventory: [],
      worldPoint: "",
      selectedBlock: 1
    };
```

When i use Console.log, it works fine,

```js
console.log(this.gameState.selectedBlock)
```

But when I try to change it through the update function,

```js
this.input.keyboard.on("keydown", function (event) {
      if (event.keyCode === 49) {
        this.gameState.selectedBlock = 1;
        //console.log("Set block to grass");
        return;
      } else if (event.keyCode === 50) {
        this.gameState.selectedBlock = 2;
        //console.log("Set block to dirt");
        return;
      } else if (event.keyCode === 51) {
        this.gameState.selectedBlock = 3;
        //console.log("Set block to stone");
        return;
      } else if (event.keyCode === 52) {
        this.gameState.selectedBlock = 4;
        //console.log("Set block to bedrock");
        return;
      }
    });
```

It Gives Me the bug "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'selectedBlock')"

I havent encountered this problem with the other two parts of the object, just this one,

what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error occurs because, you are not passing the context to the event listener. *([link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Input.InputPlugin.html))*

```
this.input.keyboard.on("keydown", function (event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 49) {
    this.gameState.selectedBlock = 1;
    //console.log("Set block to grass");
    return;
  } else if (event.keyCode === 50) {
    this.gameState.selectedBlock = 2;
    //console.log("Set block to dirt");
    return;
  } else if (event.keyCode === 51) {
    this.gameState.selectedBlock = 3;
    //console.log("Set block to stone");
    return;
  } else if (event.keyCode === 52) {
    this.gameState.selectedBlock = 4;
    //console.log("Set block to bedrock");
    return;
  }
}, this); // <-- here is context is missing
```