# This.gamestate variable not recognized (phaser.js)

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

So I've been trying to replicate the tile chebyshev lab outside of the phaser lab area, in glitch, and I've been Using the variable solution I got in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75317581/phaserjs-javascript-my-array-is-updating-too-many-times) about using Phaser.gamestate for my variable that need to be update in many locations

And my Console hits me with  `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'gameState')`

I've tried the `this` context setting too, but it continues this error, what can I do to fix it?

My Code:

```js
import Phaser from "../lib/phaser.js";

export default class Game extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super("game1");
  }

  preload() {
    this.load.image(
      "Tileset",
      "https://cdn.glitch.global/cc90578e-c3d0-47c5-bb0d-f5a81263b5b6/pixil-frame-0%20(17).png?v=1675985219390"
    );
    this.load.tilemapTiledJSON(
      "map",
      "https://cdn.glitch.global/cc90578e-c3d0-47c5-bb0d-f5a81263b5b6/Map.tmj?v=1675985261369"
    );
    this.load.spritesheet(
      "player",
      "https://cdn.glitch.global/cc90578e-c3d0-47c5-bb0d-f5a81263b5b6/pixil-frame-0%20(13).png?v=1675904194091",
      { frameWidth: 32, frameHeight: 32 }
    );
  }

  create() {
    this.gameState = {
      map: "",
      cursors: "",
    };

    this.gameState.map = this.make.tilemap({ key: "map" });
    this.tiles = this.gameState.map.addTilesetImage("tileSet", "Tileset");
    this.worldLayer = this.gameState.map.createLayer(
      "Block Layer",
      this.tiles,
      0,
      0
    );

    this.player = this.physics.add.sprite(0, 0, "player", 1);

    this.cameras.main.setBounds(
      0,
      0,
      this.gameState.map.widthInPixels,
      this.gameState.map.heightInPixels
    );
    this.cameras.main.startFollow(this.player);

    this.gameState.cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
  }

  update() {
    function updateMap() {
      console.log(this.gameState)
      var origin = this.gameState.map.getTileAtWorldXY(
        this.player.x,
        this.player.y
      );

      this.gameState.map.forEachTile(function (tile) {
        var dist = Phaser.Math.Distance.Chebyshev(
          origin.x,
          origin.y,
          tile.x,
          tile.y
        );

        tile.setAlpha(1 - 0.1 * dist);
      }, this);
    }

    if (this.gameState.cursors.left.isDown) {
      this.player.setVelocityX(-50);
      this.player.anims.play("left", true);
    } else if (this.gameState.cursors.right.isDown) {
      this.player.setVelocityX(50);
      this.player.anims.play("right", true);
    } else if (this.gameState.cursors.up.isDown) {
      this.player.setVelocityY(-50);
    } else if (this.gameState.cursors.down.isDown) {
      this.player.setVelocityY(-50);
    } else {
      this.player.setVelocityX(0);
    }

    updateMap();
  }
}
```

### Update

I've put the function outside the scene, no change whatsoever

new code

```js
import Phaser from "../lib/phaser.js";

export default class Game extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super("game1");
  }

  preload() {
    this.load.image(
      "Tileset",
      "https://cdn.glitch.global/cc90578e-c3d0-47c5-bb0d-f5a81263b5b6/pixil-frame-0%20(17).png?v=1675985219390"
    );
    this.load.tilemapTiledJSON(
      "map",
      "https://cdn.glitch.global/cc90578e-c3d0-47c5-bb0d-f5a81263b5b6/Map.tmj?v=1675985261369"
    );
    this.load.spritesheet(
      "player",
      "https://cdn.glitch.global/cc90578e-c3d0-47c5-bb0d-f5a81263b5b6/pixil-frame-0%20(13).png?v=1675904194091",
      { frameWidth: 32, frameHeight: 32 }
    );
  }

  create() {
    this.gameState = {
      map: "",
      cursors: "",
    };

    this.gameState.map = this.make.tilemap({ key: "map" });
    this.tiles = this.gameState.map.addTilesetImage("tileSet", "Tileset");
    this.worldLayer = this.gameState.map.createLayer(
      "Block Layer",
      this.tiles,
      0,
      0
    );

    this.player = this.physics.add.sprite(0, 0, "player", 1);

    this.cameras.main.setBounds(
      0,
      0,
      this.gameState.map.widthInPixels,
      this.gameState.map.heightInPixels
    );
    this.cameras.main.startFollow(this.player);

    this.gameState.cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
  }

  update() {
    if (this.gameState.cursors.left.isDown) {
      this.player.setVelocityX(-50);
      this.player.anims.play("left", true);
    } else if (this.gameState.cursors.right.isDown) {
      this.player.setVelocityX(50);
      this.player.anims.play("right", true);
    } else if (this.gameState.cursors.up.isDown) {
      this.player.setVelocityY(-50);
    } else if (this.gameState.cursors.down.isDown) {
      this.player.setVelocityY(-50);
    } else {
      this.player.setVelocityX(0);
    }

    updateMap();
  }
}

function updateMap() {
  console.log(this.gameState);
  var origin = this.gameState.map.getTileAtWorldXY(
    this.player.x,
    this.player.y
  );
  this.gameState.map.forEachTile(function (tile) {
    var dist = Phaser.Math.Distance.Chebyshev(
      origin.x,
      origin.y,
      tile.x,
      tile.y
    );

    tile.setAlpha(1 - 0.1 * dist);
  }, this);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem can be solved by moving the function `updateMap` out of the `update` function/method. Making `updateMap` a function/mehtod of the `Game` class.

Like this the `this` inside of the `updateMap` function should be pointing to the correct object.

**Sample Code snippet *(updated)*:**

```js
update() {
    if (this.gameState.cursors.left.isDown) {
       ...
    }
    ...
    // call the method
    this.updateMap();
}

// the function is now a method of the class
updateMap() {
    console.log(this.gameState)
    var origin = this.gameState.map.getTileAtWorldXY(
        this.player.x,
        this.player.y
    );
    ...
}
...
```

Comment: I've Put the function outside the scene, No change

Comment: @VatsaPandey sorry my mistake you have to call the `updateMap` _method_ like this `this.updateMap()`, and you have to remove the `function` keyword, just like in the _updated_ code snippet

Comment: This worked, but its sparked into another issue, with the origin.x coord, here

Comment: @VatsaPandey maybe `this.gameState.map.getTileAtWorldXY` doesn't return a value. you should check, if `origin` is `null`, and if so just exit the function. Since there might be cases, where `origin` might be `null`.

Comment: i've posted the Q

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75486890/chebyshev-distance-x-coordinate-bugs-when-moving