# Chebyshev distance x coordinate bugs when moving

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

So I was replicating the Phaser Chebyshev Distance example, And After a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75478712/this-gamestate-variable-not-recognized-phaser-js)
I encounter the error `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'x')` for `origin.x`,

And the strange part is, this happens after I travel a few tiles from `x=0`

code

```js
import Phaser from "../lib/phaser.js";

export default class Game extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super("game1");
  }

  preload() {
    this.load.image(
      "Tileset",
      "https://cdn.glitch.global/cc90578e-c3d0-47c5-bb0d-f5a81263b5b6/pixil-frame-0%20(17).png?v=1675985219390"
    );
    this.load.tilemapTiledJSON(
      "map",
      "https://cdn.glitch.global/cc90578e-c3d0-47c5-bb0d-f5a81263b5b6/Map.tmj?v=1675985261369"
    );
    this.load.spritesheet(
      "player",
      "https://cdn.glitch.global/cc90578e-c3d0-47c5-bb0d-f5a81263b5b6/pixil-frame-0%20(13).png?v=1675904194091",
      { frameWidth: 32, frameHeight: 32 }
    );
  }

  create() {
    this.gameState = {
      map: "",
      cursors: "",
    };

    this.gameState.map = this.make.tilemap({ key: "map" });
    this.tiles = this.gameState.map.addTilesetImage("tileSet", "Tileset");
    this.worldLayer = this.gameState.map.createLayer(
      "Block Layer",
      this.tiles,
      0,
      0
    );

    this.player = this.physics.add.sprite(0, 1600, "player", 1);

    this.cameras.main.setBounds(
      0,
      0,
      this.gameState.map.widthInPixels,
      this.gameState.map.heightInPixels
    );
    this.cameras.main.startFollow(this.player);

    this.gameState.cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
    this.physics.add.collider(this.player, this.worldLayer);
  }

  update() {
    if (this.gameState.cursors.left.isDown) {
      this.player.setVelocityX(-50);
    } else if (this.gameState.cursors.right.isDown) {
      this.player.setVelocityX(50);
    } else if (this.gameState.cursors.up.isDown) {
      this.player.setVelocityY(-50);
    } else if (this.gameState.cursors.down.isDown) {
      this.player.setVelocityY(-50);
    } else {
      this.player.setVelocityX(0);
    }

    this.updateMap();
  }
  
  updateMap() {
  console.log(this.gameState);
  var origin = this.gameState.map.getTileAtWorldXY(
    this.player.x,
    this.player.y
  );
  this.gameState.map.forEachTile(function (tile) {
    var dist = Phaser.Math.Distance.Chebyshev(
      origin.x,
      origin.y,
      tile.x,
      tile.y
    );

    tile.setAlpha(1 - 0.1 * dist);
  }, this);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are moving the player with physics velocity, the player could be outside of the map, *or on a position without a tile*.

When `map.getTileAtWorldXY` is called with a position outside of the map *(or some other invalid position)*, or there is no tile placed in that position on the layer, this function will return `null`, that's probably why you get this specific error.
*([link to the documentation](https://newdocs.phaser.io/docs/3.54.0/focus/Phaser.Tilemaps.Tilemap-getTileAtWorldXY))*

The easy solution would be just to exit the function, when the `origin` equals `null`. Like this:

```
 updateMap() {
      
    var origin = this.gameState.map.getTileAtWorldXY(
        this.player.x,
        this.player.y
    );

   if(!origin){
       return;
   }
   ...
}
```

Or you could have a variable like: `this.gameState.lastValidPosition`, that you set when the player has a valid position, and use this variable, in case of an error

```
 updateMap() {
      
    var origin = this.gameState.map.getTileAtWorldXY(
        this.player.x,
        this.player.y
    );

   if(!origin && !this.gameState.lastValidPosition ){
       // origin is invalid and we have no valid last position
       return;
   } else if( !origin ) { // origin is null, w use the last valid position
       origin = this.gameState.lastValidPosition;
   } else { // origin is not null, so we save this position
      this.gameState.lastValidPosition = origin;
   }
   ...
}
```

> Both solution will produce the **exact** same result *(for most of the usecases)*. Which os keeping the light source at the last known/valid position.

**Update:**
a more easy solution could be to use the third parameter `nonnull`, of the function `map.getTileAtWorldXY` *(if the issue is a missing tile)*, this would return a tile with index `-1` instead of `null`.

like:

```
    var origin = this.gameState.map.getTileAtWorldXY(
        this.player.x,
        this.player.y, 
        true
    );
```