# Using a DOM query selector in a Phaser function

Tags: javascript, dom, phaser-framework

I'm trying to use a Dom queryselector, with the `this.gameState` variables from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75317581/phaserjs-javascript-my-array-is-updating-too-many-times)
and it wont let me access the through the dom function or a normal function in the query select. How do I fix this?

code

```
document.querySelector("#grassBtn").addEventListener("click", function () {
    this.gameState.selectedBlock = 1;
    console.log(this.gameState.selectedBlock)
}, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass the context to the dom `addeventlistener` the way you are doing it. Since the third parameter is for the `options` or `capture` flag. *([check the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener))*.

You would have to do something like this:

**If** you are setting the eventlistener in a method of the `scene`

```
document.querySelector("#grassBtn").addEventListener("click", ()  => {
    this.gameState.selectedBlock = 1;
    console.log(this.gameState.selectedBlock)
});
```

Or *([link to the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind))*

```
document.querySelector("#grassBtn").addEventListener("click", (function() {
    this.gameState.selectedBlock = 1;
    console.log(this.gameState.selectedBlock)
}).bind(this));
```